# Run a Function From a Form

Tags: php

I want to add a function to a form, so when the submit button is clicked, a function is executed instead of leaving the page.

And I can not use $_POST, because I need the url.

Here is my script :

```
function submitclicked()
    {
    echo 'Hello World'; 

    }
    <form action="" method="post" id="TransactionAddForm">
    <input type="hidden" id="TransactionAccountID" value="'.$zpid.'" name="data[Transaction][account_id]">
    <input type="hidden" id="TransactionAmount" value="'.$_POST['price'].'" name="data[Transaction][amount]">
    <input type="hidden" id="TransactionDesc" value="'.$desc.'" name="data[Transaction][desc]">
    <input type="hidden" id="TransactionRedirectUrl" value="'.$backurl.'" name="data[Transaction][redirect_url]">
    <div class="submit"><input type="image" src="http://www.zarinpal.com/img/merchant/merchant-6.png" ></div>
    </form>;
```

Tnx for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic understanding is flawed. PHP is a server side language, meaning, it runs on the server side. It cannot capture button clicks or browser events. It can only work with requests from the client to the server.

Your function may only run **after** the form was submitted to the server.

For your problem, use JavaScript.

Also, what you have here is not a form. The user has no form controls to choose from here.

Comment: tnx for your advise. so there is no way, when a button is clicked, a function is executed and then another web page is opened. I use this form to accept purchases, but first i need to edit a set of database values, then client redirects to the payment website.

Comment: @user1391170: Set your database, and redirect using a `header("Location: new-location);`.

Comment: and how do i do that ? I'm new to PHP ( i have started learning 3 weeks ago ). I need to set a pending value in my MYSQL, so i would know this users tried to purchase something. Then client redirects to the payment webpage.then after the payment, this pending value will be deleted. ( i know how to work with MYSQL )

Answer (score 0):

Add a `return false;` at the end of the function you call on submit. This way, the form will not be submitted. You can also add a simple button, which is the type `button`, and not the type `submit`. Those buttons will also not submit the form.

-- EDIT -- 
I am assuming you want to call a JavaScript function on the click of your submit button. any PHP is of course server-side...

Comment: Read the question carefully. There's no `echo` in JavaScript, and the question is tagged PHP.

Comment: I know, I am trying to give advice on the things that ARE possible. I am suggesting any possible options using JavaScript.